# undefined reference to BlobAnalysis in class CBlobresult

Tags: algorithm, visual-c++, opencv, blobs

I am working on traffic surveillance system and now I want to detect no. of cars and classify them according to their size.I used average method to get cars as blobs and now I am trying to draw rectangles around cars by getting coordinates of the blobs I'm getting  in thresholded image.But I am getting an error while using **CblobResult**,saying "undefined reference to `BlobAnalysis(_IplImage*, unsigned char, _IplImage*, bool, bool, std::vector >&)"
How can I remove this error?

Comment: Does javacv support CBlobResult method?? I try to find it but I faild. Do i need to add additional libraries to call that method ?

Comment: which version of cvblobslib and opencv are using?